# Sql Server not updating records

Tags: sql-server

I know this is very silly question but I am not able to understand why sql server is not updating records having NULL value, if I run below query:

```
UPDATE Students SET Resultsstatus = 'Final' where Resultsstatus != 'Hidden'
```

I run the above queries in certain circumstances where I want to update result status as "Final" for all those students who has not result status as "Hidden". To update them, I am using above sql queries. But this query is working only for those records who has result status other than NULL.

For records where we have results status as NULL, sql server is not updating those records as "Final" using above query.

Can someone please let me know, what is wrong with above query? Why it is not updating those records who has current result status as NULL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: UPDATE Students SET Resultsstatus = 'Final' where Resultsstatus != 'Hidden'  OR Resultsstatus IS NULL

Comment: What does this query return: `SELECT * FROM Students where Resultsstatus != 'Hidden'`

Comment: Because `NULL` is not equal to anything, not even to `NULL`

Comment: [Also, I gently suggest `<>` vs. `!=`](https://sqlblog.org/2008/03/20/which-to-use-or).

Answer (score 3):

Because `NULL` does not equal and does not not-equal anything, **including** `NULL`. `1 != NULL` evaluates to Unknown, *not* True; and as Unknown is not True, then in a `WHERE` the row isn't returned.

When dealing with `NULL` values, you need to use `IS (NOT) NULL)`:

```
UPDATE dbo.Students
SET Resultsstatus = 'Final'
WHERE Resultsstatus != 'Hidden'  
   OR Resultsstatus IS NULL;
```

Comment: Doc link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/null-and-unknown-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

As well as the typical `WHERE Resultsstatus != 'Hidden' OR Resultsstatus IS NULL` there is another syntax you can use, which may be more performant in the presence of an index:

```sql
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT Resultsstatus
    INTERSECT
    SELECT 'Hidden')
```

This works because `INTERSECT` has different semantics for nulls than a regular `=`.

The optimizer normally elides the `EXISTS` and turns it into a standard comparison, with nullable semantics (similar to `IS DISTINCT FROM` in ANSI-SQL).

See also [Paul White](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/06/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.html) on this.