# MsSql behaves differently when filtering for an empty string by positive and negative query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just realized very strange behavior of my MsSql database when filtering empty string `!= ''` or `<> ''` regarding *NULL* values.

I have following data in the table

| ID | Value | (table X) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | (empty string) |
| 2 | NULL | (no value) |
| 3 | text | (some real text) |

This query `select * from X where Value = ''` results in:

- ID: [1]

Both queries `select * from X where Value != ''` and `select * from X where Value <> ''` result in:

- ID: [3]

**What I do not understand is, why 2nd query is not returning ID=2?**

I know the syntax for checking explicitly on null values `where Value IS NULL` so I would expect, that 2nd query would behave differently. When checking for non-empty values, I used to write `where Value <> '' AND Value IS NOT NULL`. From now on I am totally confused...

Comment: Because that is how SQL defines `NULL` values.  The queries are behaving correctly and nothing whatsoever is surprising.

Comment: Different question, same answer: [Sql Server not updating records](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65938681/2029983)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NULL does not have a string value - or any value at all, whereas ' ' is an empty string. You're looking for not empty strings in your 2nd query. NULL is not an empty string or a string at all. NULL is a "value" of no other type than NULL itself

> It is not possible to test for NULL values with comparison operators,
> such as =, <, or <>.
> https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp