# With pyodbc & SQL Server, how to insert rows into a table while skipping NULL rows

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

The code I have successfully skips duplicate rows, but it allows the insertion of more than 1 NULL rows. I would like to ignore the insertion of rows 3 and 4, so as to only have 1 null row (alot of missing data in my dataset).

```
RegionID    province    country
     1          QC       CAN                      
     2         NULL      NULL
     3         NULL      NULL
     4         NULL      NULL
     5          ON       CAN                      
     6          AB       CAN                      
     7          PA       USA                      
     8          VA       USA     
     9         NULL      USA
```

I tried adding variations to the insert statement without success. What I tried:

"WHERE (province = ? AND country = ?)... 
1- AND (province IS NOT NULL and country IS NOT NULL) 
2- OR (province IS NOT NULL and country IS NOT NULL)

My code:

```
import pyodbc
          
cursor.execute((BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT province, country FROM dbo.Region
                   WHERE (province = ? AND country = ?) )
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO dbo.Region (province, country)
       VALUES (?,?)
   END
END),province_py,country_py,province_py,country_py)

conn.commit()
```

I also tried deleting rows 3 and 4 in SQL using this query, but 0 rows were affected.

```
DELETE FROM Region
WHERE province IS NULL and country IS NULL;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sql Server not updating records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65938635/sql-server-not-updating-records)

Comment: I'm not sure how to adapt my code to delete NULL rows based on 2 columns vs your link, which shows how to change 1 column to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to remember is **that `NULL` cannot be compared to anything with `=`.** This is because `NULL` represents `UNKNOWN`, and therefore the predicate `WHERE 5 = NULL` results in `UNKNOWN`, and a `WHERE` must result in `TRUE`. Not only that, but `NULL = NULL` also fails for the same reason

**The standard way to solve this uses some rather cumbersome `AND/OR` logic:**

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1    -- NOT EXISTS doesn't care what you select unless there are other predicates
    FROM dbo.Region
    WHERE ( (province = @province OR  @province IS NULL AND province IS NULL)
        AND (country = @country OR    @country IS NULL AND country IS NULL)
    ) )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Region (province, country)
      VALUES (@province, @country)
END;
```

**But there is a much better solution possible. This uses `INTERSECT`, which takes into account nulls as you would expect:**

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT @province, @country
    INTERSECT
    SELECT province, country
    FROM dbo.Region)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Region (province, country)
      VALUES (@province, @country)
END;
```

The logic here is: create a one-row virtual table of the parameters. Intersect this with any matches on those columns from the table `Region`. Then the `IF NOT EXISTS` asks if there is no result from this.

You can do the same thing by switching to `IF EXISTS` and `EXCEPT`

---

I suggest you use proper named parameters `@province` instead of `?`