# Unable to match DBNull to NULL Column value

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

I have a web application where I am setting one of the parameters to calling a stored procedure as DBNull if the value is null like below -

```
new SqlParameter(Utilities.Constants.SpParameters.EffectiveDate,r["EffectiveDate"] == null? DBNull.Value:r["EffectiveDate"]),
```

where r["EffectiveDate"] is a value from a row of datatable column "EffectiveDate".
Now in the stored procedure I am checking if a record exists in a table with values provided by parameters. If yes thenI update the record else insert it.

There is a record for which the EffectiveDate is NULL in the table, but when I try to check and update it using IF EXISTS condition, somehow it doesn't find a match with entries having DBNull value while trying to update and proceeds to insert a new record.

I have tried the below option but to no avail -

```
1. CAST(EffectiveDate as datetime) = CAST(@EffectiveDate as Datetime) AND 

2. ISNULL (EffectiveDate ,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000') = CASE 
WHEN @EffectiveDate IS NULL THEN '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
WHEN ISDATE(@EffectiveDate) = 0 THEN '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
WHEN CAST(@EffectiveDate as datetime) = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
ELSE @EffectiveDate END

3. SET @EffectiveDate = NULLIF(@EffectiveDate, '')  before the if condition
```

The complete stored procedure is as below -

```
USE [Process1]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo]. 
[sp_Insert_Update_History]    Script Date: 4/19/2021 7:55:12 PM 
******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Insert_Update_History] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @CompanyName                VARCHAR(500),
    @Bank                       VARCHAR(100) NULL,      
    @EffectiveDate      DATETIME NULL,
    @ExpirationDate     DATETIME NULL,
    @Amount                 DECIMAL(18,2) NULL,
    @Adjustment         DECIMAL(18,2) NULL,     
    @Rec_Insert_Update_By       BIGINT,
    @Rec_Insert_Update_Flag     CHAR(1)
AS
BEGIN

BEGIN TRY
--SET @EffectiveDate = NULLIF(@EffectiveDate, '')

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.LOC_HISTORY WHERE 
                CompanyName = @CompanyName AND              
                    
                CAST(EffectiveDate as datetime) = CAST(@EffectiveDate as 
Datetime) AND 
                --ISNULL (EffectiveDate ,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000') = CASE 
                --WHEN @EffectiveDate IS NULL THEN '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
                --WHEN ISDATE(@EffectiveDate) = 0 THEN '1900-01-01 
00:00:00.000'
                --WHEN CAST(@EffectiveDate as datetime) = '1900-01-01 
00:00:00.000' THEN '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
                --ELSE @EffectiveDate END AND

            
                CAST(ExpirationDate as datetime) = CAST(@ExpirationDate as 
datetime)
                )

    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.LOC_HISTORY SET
        
        CompanyName                     =  @CompanyName        
        ,Bank                       =  @Bank  
        ,EffectiveDate              =  @EffectiveDate          
        ,ExpirationDate             =  @ExpirationDate                 
        ,Amount                         =  @Amount         
        ,Adjustment                 =  @Adjustment         
        
        ,Rec_Insert_Update_Dt               =  GETDATE()                   
        ,Rec_Insert_Update_By               =  @Rec_Insert_Update_By                   
        ,Rec_Insert_Update_Flag             =  'U'

        WHERE           
        CompanyName = @CompanyName AND
                        
                EffectiveDate = @EffectiveDate AND
                ExpirationDate = @ExpirationDate        

    END
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.LOC_HISTORY WHERE 
                CompanyName = @CompanyName AND                                      
                EffectiveDate = @EffectiveDate AND
                ExpirationDate = @ExpirationDate 
                )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.LOC_HISTORY(
          [CompanyName]
          ,[Bank]             
          ,[EffectiveDate]
          ,[ExpirationDate]
          ,[Amount]
          ,[Adjustment]           
          ,[Rec_Insert_Update_Dt]
          ,[Rec_Insert_Update_By]
          ,[Rec_Insert_Update_Flag]
          )
        
        VALUES ( 
        @CompanyName
          ,@Bank              
          ,@EffectiveDate
          ,@ExpirationDate
          ,@Amount
          ,@Adjustment                             
        , GETDATE()                
        ,@Rec_Insert_Update_By                 
        ,'I')       

                

    END 
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
END
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Waht comes back from database is DBNull.Value. So I think you need after the double equal sign  "== DBNull.Value"

Comment: In that case, there's no translation necessary.

Comment: Where's the `EXISTS` that you mentioned? Show the whole procedure, not fragments that have no context. Also, declare and pass the parameter as an actual date/time type and you can eliminate all that nasty string work that can be prone to error.

Comment: The proper way to match `NULL` to a parameter is `(@EffectiveDate IS NULL AND EffectiveDate IS NULL) OR @EffectiveDate = EffectiveDate` . You can't compare `NULL` to `NULL` because `NULL` never compares to anything (it's "unknown" so the result is also "unknown"). So you have to do separate `IS NULL` checks. Don't ever manipulate strings to compare dates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sql Server not updating records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65938635/sql-server-not-updating-records)